# detox[3338] DEBUG: [APP_STATUS] Failed to execute the current status query

Tags: expo, detox

I try to add detox to my expo application, everthing seams to work fine, but when I try to run the test I get following error message.

`detox[3338] DEBUG: [APP_STATUS] Failed to execute the current status query.`

firstTest.e2e.ts

```js
const { reloadApp } = require('detox-expo-helpers');

describe('Example', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await reloadApp({
      permissions: {
        location: 'always',
        userTracking: 'YES'
      }
    })
  });

  it('test', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('settings'))).toBeVisible()
    await element(by.id('settings')).tap()

    console.log('success')
  })
})
```

At first I start the expo server with `yarn expo start --ios` and then run the detox test with `yarn detox test -c ios --loglevel trace`. The app will be installed and loaded but stucks at the error message. Did any one has an solution?

Comment: Same issue. Could you solve it ?

Comment: Nope sadly not, just switched to maestro.